# Does Paralysis stack with Wyrdward?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I'm just curious if the [Paralysis](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/paralysis) passive (for Wizard), which gives a 15% chance for lightning damage to stun the enemy for 1.5 seconds, stacks with the ring [Wyrdward](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wyrdward)'s special, which does the same, 13-17% chance for Lightning damage to stun the enemy for 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very helpful collection about this and other item effects on the official [forum](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12187048616).It says:

> **Stacks multiplicatively with Paralysis, appears to be affected by proc scalar. The game rolls for a proc from Paralysis first.** If Paralysis is not triggered, it then looks for stun chance on equipment from things like Wyrdward. Does not interact with Lightning Hydra or similar 0 scalar skills that Paralysis does work with. As far as I can tell the only difference between Wyrdward and the blue-text stun chance that can appear as a random roll on certain items is that Wyrdward's stun chance is considerably higher but only works with lightning damage.